# PHP echoing full file, not JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, apache

I have been spending lots of time trying to figure out the issue. Nothing is working though. It continues to send the PHP file as text.

This is my javascript file with the ajax request.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

var method = "GET";

var url = "http://localhost:8000/createTable.PHP";

//send ajax request
ajax.open(method, url, true);
ajax.send();

//retrieve table data
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        //convert data to array
        alert(this.responseText);
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
```

and this is my php file which is alerted as is on my website.

```
//connect to MYSQL

require_once('../connectSQL.php');

//query

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM fitness");

//

$to_encode = array();

while ($row = mysqul_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $to_encode[] = row;

}

echo json_encode($to_encode);

mysqli_close($dbc);
//fclose($myfile);
```

My php file work fine when I'm sending json from javascript file to php for storing in database. However, now that I'm retrieving data from database, seems like the PHP file is not being read as PHP.

I have tried changing all sorts of things in httpd.conf. Using apache 7 and mac osx.

Comment: Silly question, but the file does start with `<?php`, correct?

Comment: yes, sorry it does, and ends with ?>

Comment: Uppercase php should not be a problem but maybe your webserver (apache2, nginx etc) does not consider uppercase PHP files as php files. Anyway you should make the extension of file lowercase php.

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ silly me. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must insert PHP tags, so the server understands this code as PHP

in this case it would look like this:

```
<?php

//connect to MYSQL

require_once('../connectSQL.php');

//query

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM fitness");

//

$to_encode = array();

while ($row = mysqul_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $to_encode[] = row;

}

echo json_encode($to_encode);

mysqli_close($dbc);
//fclose($myfile);

?>
```